# Passing an object in a v-for loop to a Vue method activated by a click listener

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox

I'm trying to trigger a mapbox "flyto()" method when I click on an item within a v-for loop. The data I'm iterating over includes an object for lngLat: {lng: '', lat: ''}.

I've tried a couple things just not really sure how this should be structured:

```html
<v-card v-for="(event, index) in eventDetails" :key="index">
    <v-card 
       @click="flyTo(event.lngLat)">
```

```
flyTo(lngLat) {
        this.map.flyTo({
          center: [
            lngLat.lngLat.lng,
            lngLat.lngLat.lat
          ], zoom: 16
        })
      }
```

I've also tried slight variations(but no luck) such as:

```
flyTo(lngLat) {
        this.map.flyTo({
          center: [{
            lng: lngLat.lngLat.lng,
            lat: lngLat.lngLat.lat
          }], zoom: 16
        })
      }
```

Just for reference below is an example from the mapbox website on how the flyto method should be structured (first parameter in center array is the lng, second is lat):

```
flyTo() {
  this.map.flyTo({
  center: [
    -74.50 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10,
     40 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10
   ], zoom: 16
  })
},
```

I've obviously have this structured wrong. Just not sure how it should be structured (pretty new to programming).

I would like this to pass the selected item's lngLat generated by the for loop to the flyTo method, so that the function knows where to well...flyto.

Errors I'm receiving(currently):

[Vue warn] Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'lng' of undefined"

And:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'lng' of undefined
    at VueComponent.flyTo

Comment: Why are you using `lngLat.lngLat.lng` instead of what would seem to be the more obviously correct `lngLat.lng`? Without knowing how your event objects are structured, it's hard to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks. That's all I had to do. Just wasn't that obvious to me that I could access the property of the object like that, makes sense now though. Cheers.